# Add condition to sub select in query

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.email,
    (
        SELECT
            count(DISTINCT o.id)
        FROM
            orders o
            INNER JOIN cart_dates cd ON cd.order_id = o.id
        WHERE
            u.id = o.user_id
    ) as count
FROM
    users u
```

How can I get rows only when `count` is, for example, < 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `group by` and `having` clause.

```
select u.email
from users u
inner join orders o on o.user_Id = u.id
inner join card_dates cd on cd.order_id = o.id
group by u.email
having count(distinct o.id) < 20
```

Comment: Thanks. And the query looks so much simpler.