# Add condition to two sub selects in query

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.email,
    (
        SELECT
            count(DISTINCT o.id)
        FROM
            orders o
            INNER JOIN cart_dates cd ON cd.order_id = o.id
        WHERE
            u.id = o.user_id
    ) as total,
    (
        SELECT
            count(DISTINCT o.id)
        FROM
            orders o
            INNER JOIN cart_dates cd ON cd.order_id = o.id AND o.pre_order = TRUE
        WHERE
            u.id = o.user_id
    ) as count

FROM
    users u
```

How can I get rows where for example, count > (total / 2)?

Comment: Sample data and expected result would be helpful..

Comment: I expect the email from the users that `count > (total / 2)`

Comment: It seems you already got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709945/add-condition-to-sub-select-in-query)

Comment: No, it's a different query.

Comment: so what is `total` value?

Comment: total is the alias for the first sub select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am only assumming to answer this question.

```
SELECT 
  u.email
FROM
  users u
  INNER JOIN cart_dates cd ON cd.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY
  u.email
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT Case when o.pre_order = TRUE then o.id else null end) >
  (COUNT(DISTINCT o.id)/2)
```

I tried to making it more simpler.